# How to scroll a view over another view?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to scroll a view over another view in React Native.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1
        }}>


            //THIS IS A BACKGROUND VIEW
            <BackgroundView />

            //THIS IS THE FOREGROUND VIEW
            <View style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
            }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={cards}
                    refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
                    onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => <Card {...item} />}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                    onEndReached={this.loadMore}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={2} />
            </View>
        </View>
    )

}
```

I want the foreground view, which contains the `FlatList` to scroll over the `BackgroundView`

I have tried using `position:absolute` on the `ForegroundView` but the `FlatList` stopped working and I could not scroll.

EDIT : Initially the `BackgroundView` is shown (contains some intro content), with the `ForegroundView` on the bottom partially, and as the user scrolls on the screen, The `ForegroundView` is scrolled over it

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

For your background view use the style '...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject', or:

```
{ position: ('absolute': 'absolute'),
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
}
```

As noted in the comment depending of your design, the foreground will often fill the entire View, making the background impossible to interact with.

The only solution I have found is making the foreground positionned absolute and cover the minimal surface as possible. It works if the view is kept simple.

Example here for a button container on the bottom of the screen, that does not overlaps top, left and right of the Background:

```
bottomButtonContainer: {
  position: 'absolute',
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
  bottom: 0,
  marginVertical: 5,
  marginHorizontal: '25%',
  width: '50%',
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'center',
},
```

Comment: This works, but the ForegroundView fills the entire screen, making the BackgroundView unusable. So I tried putting a zIndex on a certain element of the BackgroundView, But zIndex isn't working as expected.